# placed to vs placed in

Tags: vocabulary

Which sentence is correct? The sentence is to be understood in a mathematical/CS context.

The nodes are **placed to** a random location on a plane.

or

The nodes are **placed in** a random location on a plane.

I tried to google it, but it did not came out with a convincing enough result.

Comment: "Placed at..." a location is a point in space. https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-place-at-in-on.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better alternative of your two examples is

> placed in

since the nodes are placed *inside* a location.

However, better might be

> placed at

to signify that the nodes are placed (exactly) in a particular location.